# iOS Swift mobile FFMpeg says Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg

I run the following FFmpeg command in iOS Swift

```
-i 'record_merge.mp4' -i 'text_0.png' -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=208:438:enable='between(t,0.0,5.5316668)';" -c:a copy 'texted_video.mp4'
```

FFmpeg says

> No such filter: '' Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument

What is wrong with my FFmpeg command?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the ';' at the end of the `-filter_complex` parameter.
The command should be

```
-i 'record_merge.mp4' -i 'text_0.png' -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=208:438:enable='between(t,0.0,5.5316668)'" -c:a copy 'texted_video.mp4'
```

`'between(t,0.0,5.5316668)';"` -> `'between(t,0.0,5.5316668)'"`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).